# 'rnd' error - scikit learn tutorial for multioutput classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mnist

The code I've been using (identical to the code in the tutorial book) is pictured below for multioutput classification with scikit learn. I was getting the error that 'rnd' was not defined so imported random as rnd. now, I'm getting the error 
*'TypeError: randint() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given'* If anyone is able to have a look at the code and try guide me as to how to amend this error that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
    noise = rnd.randint(0, 100, (len(X_train), 784))
    noise = rnd.randint(0, 100, (len(X_test), 784))
    X_train_mod = X_train + noise
    X_test_mod = X_test + noise
    y_train_mod = X_train
    y_test_mod = X_test
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to use *randint()* from *random* in **numpy**, and so using:

```
import numpy.random as rnd

noise = rnd.randint(0, 100, (len(X_train), 784))
noise = rnd.randint(0, 100, (len(X_test), 784))
```

will work.